# how to show pop up in react , getting error on button click?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

could you please tell me how to show pop up in react, getting an error on button click?

I am getting an error on button click

```
Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?
```

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/embed/6y402kly73

```
showSignInPopUp = () => {
    console.log(this.props.actions)
    this.props.actions.showHideLoginPopup(true);
  };
```

Comment: Also Include action file in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your ***loginActions*** does not have the required parameter `type`. Change like this

```
return {
 type: types.SHOW_HIDE_LOGIN_POPUP,
 payload: visibility
}
```

You have another error in your ***login.reducer***,

```
switch (action.type) {
case types.SHOW_LOGIN_POPUP: // Change to SHOW_HIDE_LOGIN_POPUP
  state = action.payload;
  return state;
default:
  return state;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: still nt display popup

Answer (score 0):

You must give key name `type` in action object.

```
// wrong object key name
export function showHideLoginPopup(visibility){
   return {
     action: types.SHOW_HIDE_LOGIN_POPUP,
     payload: visibility
   }
}
```

You should write like this

```
export function showHideLoginPopup(visibility){
   return {
     type: types.SHOW_HIDE_LOGIN_POPUP,
     payload: visibility
   }
}
```

Hope it will be help

Comment: still not display pop up

Comment: @naveen That's because your action type is not handled in the reducer correctly... it should be SHOW_HIDE_LOGIN_POPUP instead of SHOW_LOGIN_POPUP. Check login.reducer.js (check here https://codesandbox.io/s/l91r41092z)